# Mysql, is it possible to get the total sums before doing calculation?

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to do a calculation base on the condition but i got an error `Error Code: 1111 Invalid use of group function`

```
select sum( price - (price * if(sum(price)>200, 0.5, 0) ) ) from mytables; -- error
```

what i'm trying to do is, if the total sum of all `price` more than 200, than the calculation goes like this `price - (price * 0.5)` otherwise, `price - (price * 0)`

**UPDATED**

so if we sum all we will get `471`, so the condition is true which is `more than 200`, so by right the formula should be like this `price - (price * 0.5)` so the answer/output should be `235.5`

below are my schema: [link to db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2omg1JdQF4QWYUBezt7VMJ/2)

```
CREATE TABLE `mytables` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role_id` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `mytables` (`id`, `role_id`, `name`, `price`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'nameA', '32'),
  ('2', '3', 'nameB', '45'),
  ('3', '1', 'nameC', '3'),
  ('4', '1', 'nameD', '86'),
  ('5', '3', 'nameE', '45'),
  ('6', '2', 'nameF', '31'),
  ('7', '3', 'nameG', '96'),
  ('8', '1', 'nameH', '87'),
  ('9', '2', 'nameI', '34'),
  ('10', '1', 'nameJ', '12');
```

Comment: Aggregate functions cannot be nested. *if the total sum of all score more than 200* What is `score`? Show desired output with detailed explanations.

Comment: Why do you need to sum? Every row seems to contain an unique individual.

Comment: There's no score here, and `score - (score * 0)` is just a fancy way of saying `score`

Comment: And `score - (score * 0.5)` a fancy way of saying `0.5 * score`.

Comment: sorry @all , i've updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for this:

```
SELECT SUM(price) * IF(SUM(price) > 200, 0.5, 1.0) FROM mytables;
```

The outcome is 235.5.

I've use the simplified expressions. `price - (price * 0)` is equal to `price` and `price - (price * 0.5)` is equal to `0.5 * price`. So it's either 1.0 times the `price` or 0.5 times the `price` based on the `price`.

I sum all prices up using `SUM()`. I use a `IF()` to calculate the factor that is applied to this summed price.

I would like to suggest to use a better name for the table.

Comment: i've updated my question the output should be 235.5

Comment: @LearnProgramming: It is still quite unclear what you're trying to calculate. I've changed my answer to get the result you want, but I'm not sure it will always do what you want.